# Recommendations for sites / articles / books on developing web sites in Ruby without using a framework such as Rails / Merb

Tags: ruby

Im struggling to find good material about developing web applications in Ruby without using a framework such as Rails or Merb in the usual places (I've already spent a while on Google, Safari books online and stackoverflow looking!). I have nothing against the frameworks at all; just my intended architecture is a little different and so doesnt fit well.

Can you give some recommendations on resources you have found useful?

Comment: I might help people give a better answer if you give us some idea what type of 'architecture' you have in mind.

Comment: Im intending to use Amazon's SimpleDb as the back-end and hence dont want to be tied to an ORM (e.g. ActiveRecord). Apache / Passenger on EC2 as front end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should give [Sinatra](http://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/tree/master) a try. It's a framework, but a minimalistic one, so you can easily see what is going on under the hood.

Other than that maybe the [CGI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/index.html) Ruby library is a place to look into.

Comment: Thanks - Sinatra does seem to be a better fit with what Im trying to do

Answer (score 2):

If you are intending a home brewed approach I can highly recommend Ruby Cookbook published by O'Reilly. It's one of the most useful Ruby books I've bought and has a some very good chapters (14 - 16) on internet programming.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [rack](http://rack.rubyforge.org/), it's THE way to do ruby web apps without using a preexisting framework. From the docs:

"A Rack application is an Ruby object (not a class) that responds to call. It takes exactly one argument, the environment and returns an Array of exactly three values: The status, the headers, and the body."

If a minimal framework will suffice then I recommend [waves](http://rubywaves.com/)

Answer (score 1):

[Webby](http://webby.rubyforge.org/) is worth a look. Simple, but useful for some applications.